# My Android studio project cant run after restart my pc

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After I restart my laptop, I have a problem with my project on android studio.
when I open android studio I see [image: this phot]
that shows run btn is disabled. and my left menu is changed.
I confused with this problem.
and there is no "Android" option on dropdown , [image: this photo]
and this is my edit configuration view: [image: photo3]

Answer (score 0):

Click here and select `Android`. Your run option will appear.

[image]

From My Sample project

[image]

Comment: there is no "android" option there. I add photo to question

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that did repair my project.
there was an error on bottom right side of android studio that told "plugins are disable"
I clicked on it and another window opens then I checked options and press OK.
so after that it suggests to restart android studio.
the there was all right.
Excuse me for my English. I will thanks to some one that edits my answer to correct English.